# Why the method inner_join is giving error which ran successfully once

Tags: r, inner-join

I am trying to join 2 dataframes "UnmatchIMISCode" and "AllSchemeSanctionNo" using inner_join using following code snippet in R.

```
MatchByGo <- UnmatchIMISCode %>% inner_join(select(AllSchemeSanctionNo, schCd, schNm, imisSchCd, slsscdate, admApprvNo, sanctionno,
                                                  sanctiondate, estCostTot, allotTotAmt, expTotAmt),
                                           by = c('Admin Sanction No.' = 'sanctionno') )
```

It ran successfully many a times but now it shows error as follows:

```
Error in UseMethod("inner_join") : 
  no applicable method for 'inner_join' applied to an object of class "c('sheets_id', 'drive_id', 'vctrs_vctr', 'character')"
```

What went wrong as I did not modify the code

Comment: The error message suggests that at least one of `UnmatchIMISCode` and `AllSchemeSanctionNo` is not a dataframe. If they are indeed both dataframes, perhaps your `select` function has been overwritten by another package loaded after the one you expect - to avoid any conflict try using the form `dplyr::select(...)` (assuming that is the one you are expecting).

Comment: Please post fuller code for context and not a single line snippet. Possibly somewhere before the `inner_join`  you are overwriting these data frame objects or you are running your code interactively like in RStudio and these objects are changing in your global environment and so this earlier line fails.

Comment: @AndrewGustar Thanks for the suggestion. UnmatchIMISCode changed to class "sheets_id"  "drive_id"   "vctrs_vctr" "character". This happened as I wrote the output to a Google sheet and at the same assigned the output to UnmatchIMISCode.